# Npgsql is not able to talk to PostgreSQL after upgrading from postgresql 9.x to postgresql 13

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, npgsql

After upgrading a PostgreSQL server to version 13, Npgsql is no longer able to connect.  This is a .NET application.  Communications was verified via the command line psql command.  I can not seem to get any useful errors from the developer to further investigate.  I did have the developer upgrade Npgsql to version 5.0.1.1, to no avail.

Any tips on debugging further would be greatly appreciated!

```
ERROR 2020-12-16 16:02:44,499 333535ms Archive                rieveUnlimitedData - Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during reading attempt
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|194_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageSequential|0>d.MoveNext()
```

Test with psql:

```sh
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin>psql.exe -h XXX.XXXX.com -U postgres -d ais
Password for user postgres:
psql (13.1, server 13.0)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

ais=# \d
                 List of relations
  Schema  |       Name        |   Type   |  Owner
----------+-------------------+----------+----------
 public   | geography_columns | view     | postgres
```

This is all the code I could get:

```
<add name="rawDB"
     connectionString="server=host05.xxxxxx.local;port=5432;database=ais;uid=xxxxxxxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxxxxx;timeout=30;commandtimeout=30" providerName="Npgsql"
/>
var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["rawDB"].ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
var cmdSel = new NpgsqlCommand(queryText, connection);
```

Comment: It would be good to see the code that caused the error.

Comment: The remote server is a fresh install of PostgreSQL 13. I upgraded the local client from version PostgreSQL 9.5 to PostgreSQL 13 simply for the command line psql command that supports the newer scram-sha-256 hashing algorithm. I did this to prove to the developer that it was not a firewall issue or general server configuration issue. I believed it was a compatibility issue between npgsql 4.x and PostgreSQL v13. After upgrading to npgsql 5.x I'm now at a bit of a loss as to how to proceed. I will try to get the actual code, but often times that is difficult.

Comment: Does npgsql log in such a generic way that a more useful/detailed error maybe available by increasing the verbosity?
Does npgsql rely on the exiting PostgreSQL server installed for code (linked like dll) when connecting to the remote PostgreSQL server?

Comment: I read:
"Npgsql will send the password in MD5 or in cleartext (not recommended)."
https://www.npgsql.org/doc/security.html
By default PostgreSQL v13 supports scram-sha-256. Does npgsql not support scram-sha-256?

Comment: Version 4.0 or better should support scram-sha-256. Without knowing the code that causes the error, everything is guesswork.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe This is all I have so far:

`<add name="rawDB" connectionString="server=host05.xxxxxx.local;port=5432;database=ais;uid=xxxxxxxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxxxxx;timeout=30;commandtimeout=30" providerName="Npgsql" />

var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["rawDB"].ConnectionString);

connection.Open();

var cmdSel = new NpgsqlCommand(queryText, connection);`

Is there a specific reason you suggest npgsql 4.x over npgsql 5.x?

Comment: I don't suggest that you use anything but the most recent version (I said "4.0 or better"). Does the error occur while you connect to the database or while you execute the query? Perhaps the solution is simply that the query execution took longer than the query timeout? [The documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#timeouts-and-keepalive) suggests that that is 30 seconds by default.

Comment: To add to what @LaurenzAlbe wrote, a full stack trace is needed here - it's important to know whether this is a connection error or an execution error. 5.0.11 has improved timeout logic which may cause very long queries to fail (e.g. CommandTimeout is now respected with async execution).

Comment: @ShayRojansky I have posted what I think you are asking for...
https://gist.github.com/infotek/f18fffd050bb6603b42da802d6b98e1c

Comment: The stack trace indeed shows the the error is on execution, not connection open. Can you try setting CommandTimeout to 0 on the command - disabling the timeout entirely - and confirm whether that makes the error go away? There's the possibility this is a legitimate timeout that wasn't being triggered in previous versions.

Comment: @ShayRojansky the developer used 
<add name="rawDB" connectionString="server=web05.server.com;port=5432;database=ais;uid=********;password=**********;timeout=30;commandtimeout=0" providerName="Npgsql" />
and it now functions as expected!

Answer (score 2):

commandtimeout=0 solved the issue.  I suspect the increased time for authentication (SASL exchange) cause the issue to occur after changing from PostgreSQL v9.x to PostgreSQL v13.x.

Comment: Note that Command Timeout affects command execution, whereas authentication is about opening new physical connection - so that doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: It's important to confirm that there isn't a bug in Npgsql 5.0 - can you please verify whether the queries that were timing out were actually running for very long, i.e. whether the timeout was actually the correct behavior (even if it didn't occur before 5.0)? If not, can you help put together some sort of code sample?

Comment: @ShayRojansky I will attempt to allocate some time to this next week.